# How do I get the filename from the source value supplied by filebeat in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I want to get the filename from the source value provided by filebeat.

```
output {
  if [type] == "wxnumber" {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        sniffing => false
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[source]}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
  }
}
```

The `%{[source]}` is usually like `/aaa/bbb/ccc.log`. How do I set the index to the `ccc.log`?

Comment: What's the result you're getting, from the above config?

Comment: @ Kulasangar , Thank for you reply. The result of %{[source]} is like /aaa/bbb/ccc.log. I just want get the ccc.log for this variable.

Comment: I've updated the answer! Check if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't know the filename. Maybe it will be ddd.log, eee.log, fff.log and so on.

Comment: What if you use a regex in order to trim the path and get only certain value as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241515/trim-field-value-or-remove-part-of-the-value)

Comment: Thank you Kulasangar, I have solved my issue, Then I use gsub, it can convert all slashes to any wanted.

Comment: Great it worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use the `mutate` in order to replace it with how your log file should be named:

```
if [%{[source]}] =~ /aaa/bbb/ccc.log {
  mutate {
     replace => ["%{[source]}]", "ccc.log"]
  }
}
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241515/trim-field-value-or-remove-part-of-the-value) might be helpful!